# Observer pattern and inheritance: Not calling the correct function

Tags: c++, inheritance, observer-pattern

I am trying to implement the Observer pattern for a game I am creating for a school project.

I have created 2 virtual classes, Observer and Observable.

Observer.h:

```
#ifndef OBSERVER_H
#define OBSERVER_H
#include <vector>

class Observable;

class Observer
{
    public:
     Observer();
     virtual ~Observer();
     virtual void update(Observable* ob) =0;
};

#endif
```

Observer.cpp:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "Observer.h"


 Observer::Observer()
 {
 }

 Observer::~Observer()
 {
 }
```

Observable.h:

```
#ifndef OBSERVEABLE_H
#define OBSERVEABLE_H
#include <vector>
#include "Observer.h"


class Observable
{
    protected:
    std::vector<Observer*> observers;
    public:
    Observable();
    virtual ~Observable();
    virtual void attach(Observer *a);
    virtual void detach(Observer *a);
    virtual void notify();
};

#endif
```

Observable.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Observable.h"

Observable::Observable()
{
}

Observable::~Observable()
{
}

void Observable::attach(Observer *a)
{
    observers.push_back(a);
}

void Observable::detach(Observer *a)
{
     for (auto it = this->observers.begin(); it < this->observers.end(); it++) 
     {

            if (*it == a) 
            {
            this->observers.erase(it);
            break;
            }
     }
 }

void Observable::notify()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++)
        observers[i]->update(this);
}
```

I have a Map class that inherits from Observable, and a mapView class that inherits from Observer (Map is very long, I only included the relevant functions)

Map.h:

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H
#include "Observable.h"
#include <iostream>

class Map : public Observable
{
    public:
    Map();
    ~Map();
    void getLatest();
    void notify();
};

#endif
```

Map.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Map.h"

Map::Map()
{
}

Map::~Map()
{
}

void Map::getLatest()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "This is the latest info!" << endl;
}
```

mapView.h:

```
#ifndef MAP_V_H
#define MAP_V_H
#include "Observer.h"
#include "Map.h"
#include "Plants.h"

class mapView : public Observer
{
    public:
    mapView();
    ~mapView();
    void update(Map* map);
};

#endif
```

mapView.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mapView.h"
#include "Map.h"

mapView::mapView()
{
}

mapView::~mapView()
{
}

void mapView::update(Map* map)
{
    map->getLatest();
}
```

Finally, my main simply creates a Map and a mapView, attaches the mapView, and calls map.notify()

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "setUp.h"
#include "Map.h"
#include "mapView.h"

int main()
{
    Map gameMap;
    mapView view;
    gameMap.attach(&view);

    gameMap.notify();

    return 0;
}
```

I run into a number of issues here. I cannot create a mapView item because the compiler says I never implemented an override version of update(Observable* ob).... I tried with update(Map* map) but it appears that despite the fact that Map inherits from Observable, it does not seem to count as the same signature, so it won't compile.

I attempted to change my mapView::update() function to take a pointer to Observable instead, but this won't work because the function calls something from Map class.

I then tried changing the update function to NOT be a virtual function (with empty implementation in the virtual class), but it seems any time I try to pass a Map to update, it will call the base class function and not the mapView version. In other words, getLatest() is never called.

I am now pretty confused because this sort of goes against how I thought polymorphism worked. Would appreciate some help or insight if possible!

Thank you,

Comment: Template is your friend here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base class declares:

```
virtual void update(Observable* ob) =0;
```

You derived class declares:

```
void update(Map* map);
```

These are not the same signature. If you used the new `override` keyword, you would see at compile time that you were not in fact overriding the virtual method.

If you **know** you'll only get `Map`s, then you can just use `static_cast`. But it's safer to use `dynamic_cast`:

```
void update(Observable* o) override { // now we're ok
    if (auto map = dynamic_cast<Map*>(o)) {
        // okay, got a Map
        // ....
    }
    else {
        // huh?
    }
}
```

---

**Super brief type theory digression**. The typical rule for overrides is *co*variant in return and *contra*variant in the argument type. You can specify a more-derived return type, or a more-base argument type. Think about it this way - if you have a base class function taking and returning a `Car*`... your argument can be a `Car*` (that's exactly what's expected), or it can be a `Vehicle*` (since anything you can do with a `Vehicle`, you can do with a `Car` - this still works), but it can't be a `SportsCar*` (since the caller might pass you a `Car` that isn't a `SportsCar` and justifiably expect this to work!) It doesn't make sense for the derived class to accept only `Map`s - you have to be able to accept any `Observable`s, even not `Map`s!

Comment: Would like to emphasize how great the `override` keyword is, you should always use it when working w/ virtual functions!

Comment: Thank you! This has solved my issues. I had thought about using dynamic cast as I had seen it before, but I wasn't using it correctly. Would you say this is the standard way to override a function when you know you expect a derived class to be passed as parameters? Say, when implementing an Observer pattern, for example.

Comment: @waffledave I dunno about "standard", but it's a pretty reasonable thing to do.